# Unicode filename in MicroFocus Native Cobol

Tags: cobol, microfocus

In this file declaration:

```
   select bank-file assign to f-bank-file
          organization line sequential
          file status is wx-fstat.
```

Variable **f-bank-file** must be **PIC X**. Is there any way to make it **PIC N**? I need to open file with chinese chars in name.

Comment: What happens if you define `77 f-bank-file-n  PIC N` and then `MOVE f-bank-file-n TO f-bank-file` (or, likely more reasonable a possibly new parent for `f-bank-file`?

Comment: It doesn't help, or I am unable to find proper setup. If I have PIC N in any level or hierarchy in variable, that goes to filename, program crashes when I am trying open file

Comment: Have you tried making f-bank-file a group level and then have your PIC N subordinate to it?

Comment: Yes, it's still crashing.

Comment: I'd try to do the following: rename the variable `f-bank-file` to `f-bank-file-ext` (if you like to make it more obvious also change the clause to `ASSIGN TO 'f-bank-file'` (= using a literal), then `SET ENVIRONMENT 'f-bank-file' TO f-bank-file-ext`, if that doesn't work try to setup the file mapping externally in the calling shell script in a terminal that uses the appropriate LANG value).

Comment: I don't believe Unicode or UTF-8 filenames are supported on Windows because the CBL_OPEN_FILE APIs don't support them and it is unclear in the LRM if PIC N/U are valid in this circumstance either.

(Unix/Linux has no concept of Unicode/UTF-8 filenames)

I would raise this as an issue with Micro Focus support or continue the conversation on community.microfocus.com